# Is there any way to add video over image without position absolute for video tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Design requirement: there is a background image of iPhone and on top of that there is a video tag playing video in loop.
All answers related to this problem were making video tag absolute on top of that image background. but it will cause problem while resizing window size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without positioning absolute video tag over image & it would help in responsiveness while changing window size.Check the below css and html code for this purpose.

```
<div id="tv_container">
 <video autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos- 
        bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </source>
 </video>
</div>

#tv_container {
 background-image: url('../img/mobile-no-send.png');
 width: 24%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-left:  1.8%;
 padding-right:  1.6%;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
 padding-top: 3.3%;
}

video {
  max-width:100%; 
  max-height:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: fill;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
```